# Building a multi-architecture Docker image, but Dockerfile requires different packages depending on architecture

Tags: docker

I am experimenting with docker's `buildx` and noticed that everything seems to be straight forward except for one thing. My Dockerfile needs to pull certain packages depending on the architecture.

For example, here's a piece of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM XYZ

# Set environment variable for non-interactive install
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Run basic commands to update the image and install basic stuff.
RUN apt update && \
    apt dist-upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" && \
    apt autoremove -y && \
    apt clean -y && \
    ...
    # Install amazon-ssm-agent
    mkdir /tmp/ssm && \
    curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/debian_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.deb -o /tmp/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.deb && \
```

As you can see from above, the command is set to pull down the Amazon SSM agent using a hard-coded link.

What's the best way to approach this? Should I just modify this Dockerfile to create a bunch of if conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker automatically defines [a set of ARGs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope) for you when you're using the BuildKit backend (which is now the default).  You need to declare that `ARG`, and then (within the `RUN` command) you can use an environment variable `$TARGETOS` to refer to the target operating system (the documentation suggests `linux` or `windows`).

```sh
FROM ...
# Must be explicitly declared, and after FROM
ARG TARGETOS
# Then it can be used like a normal environment variable
RUN curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-$TARGETOS/...
```

There is a similar `$TARGETPLATFORM` if you need to build either x86 or ARM images, but its syntax doesn't necessarily match what's in this URL.  If `$TARGETPLATFORM` is either `amd64` or `arm`, you may need to reconstruct the [Debian architecture string](https://www.debian.org/ports/#portlist-released).  You can set a shell variable within a single `RUN` command and it will last until the end of that command, but no longer.

```sh
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
RUN DEBARCH="$TARGETPLATFORM"; \
    if [ "$DEBARCH" = "arm" ]; then DEBARCH=arm64; fi; \
    curl .../debian-$DEBARCH/...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me accomplish the goal!